# Matlab: for loop only storing one result

Tags: matlab, for-loop, store

Hi I am running the following:

```
for i = 1: length(tptestseqs)
    [pstates,logscore] = hmmdecode(tptestseqs{i},t,e);
end
```

however logscore(2) and above are out of bound. it appears to have only stored the first result.

I have tried

```
for i = 1: length(tptestseqs)
    [pstates{i},logscore{i}] = hmmdecode(tptestseqs{i},t,e);
end
```

but get

```
??? Comma separated list expansion has cell syntax for an array that
is not a cell.
```

how can I store all the results of looping through the function **hmmedecode()**?

Thanks.

Comment: try clearing `pstates` and `logscore` before running your code. I'm guessing the cell array syntax should work.

Comment: @am304 yep that worked. how do i "accept" your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussion in the comments:

Try clearing `pstates` and `logscore` before running your code. I'm guessing the cell array syntax should work.

Comment: Yes, And try to pre-allocate the size of your cell array with `pstates = cell([1 length(tptestseqs)]);`